# Find consecutive values from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I want to part some sql table to ranges

this table has to be parted,

```
Id  num
0   1
0   2
2   2
2   5
```

result will be like this,

id, minimum, maximum

```
id  min     max
0   1   2
2   2   2
2   5   5
```

Comment: I can discern no logic by which you have e.g. three different ranges for `id = 0`.

Comment: What "sql" tag has to do with "html table" ?

Comment: @MaciejLos, i need sql query. its just an exmaple.

Comment: click run code snippet to see the result of what needed to be @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the question so that your example renders correctly. Right now, we'd have to save the HTML to a file, open it in a browser, just to see your example. Don't expect people to run an *HTML* snippet that has nothing to do with a *SQL* question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know really how to show the table in diffrent way

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Now that we can see the table, it's still unclear what you are asking. It looks like you are trying to find islands ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Micrsoft sql server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can see the first table, after sql query I want the second table result, It means I want to find ranges by any id. the ranges of id 0, ranges of id 1, and any id will be

Comment: This doesn't say anything. You may want to find islands in the data, or you may have used some other arbitrary logic. *You have* to specify what you want, not force us to guess. Anyway, *gaps and islands* is the category of this specific problem. You'll find many solutions, eg [this](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions) or [this](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos part the first table to ranges. if there is consecutive numbers, its a range. like id 0 has 1,2,3 - the range is min: 1, max: 3. if has 1,3 the range is: min:1, max :1, another range is min:3, max: 3

Comment: A range for 0 is 1 to 9, 1 is 1 to 6 and 2 1 to 5. I do not understand how you want to achieve other result (as is descibed above). Based on what criteria?

Comment: @MaciejLos it seems the OP wants to retrieve islands in `num` for each `id`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to find islands in `num` for different values of `id`. This is a relatively common problem so you'll find several answers in SO that deal with islands.

There are various ways to achieve this but one of the simplest is described in the "Normal Islands" section in [Solving Gaps and Islands](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions):

```
WITH C AS
(
    SELECT id,num, num - DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id,num) AS grp
    FROM islandtest
)
SELECT id,MIN(num) AS rangestart, MAX(num) AS rangeend
FROM C
GROUP BY grp,id;
```

Within each island, both `num` and `DENSE_RANK` increase by 1 for each subsequent row,  which means that the value `num - DENSE_RANK` remains constant and can be used as an island identifier.

On the next island, `DENSE_RANK` will still increase by 1 but `num` will increase by a different amount so the next island will have a different island id.

Once you have the island identifier you can group by it and retrieve the min, max values of `num`

Testing with this script:

```
declare @islandtest table (Id int, num int);

insert into @islandtest values
(0,1),
(0,2),
(2,2),
(2,5);

WITH C AS
(
    SELECT id,num, num - DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id,num) AS grp
    FROM @islandtest
)
SELECT id,MIN(num) AS rangestart, MAX(num) AS rangeend
FROM C
GROUP BY grp,id;
```

Produces the requested output:

```
id          rangestart  rangeend
----------- ----------- -----------
0           1           2
2           2           2
2           5           5
```